# keep alive image bugs

Tags: apache, keep-alive, image-loading

Recently I've been experimenting with keep-alive settings and I've realized some startling bugs with respect to image loading.

In firefox <4, some images won't even load with a timeout of 5 seconds.

In chrome at 5 seconds, the page loads normally, but at the default 15 seconds, some images get loaded where other images should.

Has anyone experienced this bug? I suppose keeping it off may be the most 'safe' solution. But I still feel as though there could be something flying over my head.

Comment: Can you give us your server to go with browser and check?

Comment: unfortunately not as its still in development and not open to the public, sorry about that